# How do i find whether my data is in item List

Tags: vb.net, search, foreach, contains, loops

in vb.net
i am having `myList as List(of myClass)` and `myData as myClass`

So how do i find whether if **myList** contains **myData** or not?

currently i am doing it like:

```
dim myList as List(of myClass) = myClasses.GetData()
dim myData as myClass = myClasses.getData(1)

for each Item as myClass in myList
   if Item.uin = myData.uin then
       msgbox 'yeah'
   end if
next
```

what can be the next better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List should have a Contains() method that does what you want.

If you want the offset, use indexOf().

Edit: if for some reason your list does not contain the same objects, and you must compare their "uin" field for equality, the easiest will be to use LINQ:

```
myList.Any(Function(item) item.uin = myData.uin)
```

Otherwise, the generic List has an Exists() method that takes a predicate:

```
myList.Exists(Function(item) item.uin = myData.uin)
```

Sorry my VB.NET is not too fluent (C# person myself), so let me know if I made any typos in there.

Comment: i tried using contains it doesn't works properly for me... it returns false even if it contains that element. can i get reference to some examples

Comment: "uin" isn't unique then?  Contains/indexOf will only test if the object is in the list, not whether that is an object in the list with the "uin" property equals to a particular value.  So, your GetData() returns a list that contains objects that are different from the objects you get from using getData(x).  Strange.